# install Windows Phone 8 API documentation locally

Tags: windows-phone-8

does anybody know if the Windows phone 8 MSDN Documentation can be installed locally?
I want this content:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402535%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
visible in Help Viewer 2.0 since I often have to work in offline scenarios.
I have installed VS 2012 and the WP8 SDK.
When I choose "Windows Phone Development" in the Help Viewer 2.0 installed with VS2012 I get the 7.1 documentation.

Manfred

Answer (score 4):

Just go inside Visual Studio.
Click "Help - Add and Remove Help Content"

Under "Recommended Documentation"

you will see "Windows Phone Development",

probably as the last item.

Click "Add" next to the item,

then click "Update" in the lower right.

The docs (approximately 209 megabytes worth) will pull down to your local machine.